# Error in bs4 when the code loops the second time

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests



murl = ['https://www.amazon.in/dp/B07XY541GH/','https://www.amazon.in/dp/B085J17VVP/']

def track(url):
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html5lib')

    pr = soup.find('span', id='priceblock_ourprice').getText()
    con_pr = pr[1:]
    converted_price = con_pr.strip()
    newprice = ''
    for con in converted_price:
        if con != ',':
            newprice = newprice + con
    newprice = float(newprice)
    return newprice

def main():
    for url in murl:
        price = track(url)
        print(price)

main()
```

I always seem to get this when the code loops the second time. Even if I store the url in two different variables and call the function one by one I still get the same error.

```
2990.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 25, in main
    price = track(url)
  File "test.py", line 13, in track
    pr = soup.find('span', id='priceblock_ourprice').getText()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution, try that out:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

murl = ['https://www.amazon.in/dp/B07XY541GH/', 'https://www.amazon.in/dp/B085J17VVP/']


def track(url):
    req = requests.get(url, headers={
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.87 Safari/537.36"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html5lib')

    pr = soup.find('span', id=lambda x: x and x.startswith('priceblock_')).text
    con_pr = pr[1:]
    converted_price = con_pr.strip()
    newprice = ''
    for con in converted_price:
        if con != ',':
            newprice = newprice + con
    newprice = float(newprice)
    return newprice


def main():
    for url in murl:
        price = track(url)
        print(price)


main()
```

1. Use missed user-aget. Mostly it should be present for parsing
2. Element tag object doesn't have getText() method
3. Id was not same for both sites

Comment: @GilbertRothanglien can you upvote my answer please?